# JavaScript init function and its use

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and saw a coode where a `init` function is used while declaring the object..I tried searching for "JavaScript init functions" but it does not take me to any correct document. Also, it does not provide me the exact application of this function…

I have modelled a function on how it looks like

```
var1 = Class.extend({
 init : function(){ alert ('Hi'}
}
```

Question:

1. How does init does called? Is it similar to the init(initialization) method in Object oriented concepts.
2. Can you please provide a example on how init function could be called?

Comment: It would be handled by your library that provides the Class object. Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

init is a custom function name, it may be called by the framework or by the object constructor and usually keeps place of a post construction method. For instance I declare it for jQuery plugins, like this:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "Display", defaults = {    
      cols : 32,
      rows : 16
    };

// The actual plugin constructor
 function Display(element, options) {
   // Object variables
   this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
   this.size = {};
   // Post construct
   this.init();
 }

 // methods of the Display 
 display.prototype =  {
   init : function() {
    this.setSize(this.options.rows, this.options.cols);
   },
   setSize : function(rows, cols) {
      // calculates size
   }
 };

 // JQuery Plugin declaration
 // ...  

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

With this, a call (from the correct scope) to `new Display()` will call the `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

Init in most framework is used to be called after the object initialization. It is called automaticaly so you just put in the code you want to execute after the object is initialized. It is similar to constructor however it is not the same. For an example in backbone which is cool javascript framework (you see this init functions only in frameworks it is not native javascript method) 
Constructor runs before Backbone sets up the structure. initialize is called inside the structure's constructor function. So basically if you need to augment anything before Backbone sets up the structure, use constructor if you need to augment anything after Backbone sets up the structure use initialize.